# Донька vs дочка в офіційних документах

Tags: різниця-між-словами, legal-terms

Чи обидва ці слова можуть бути використані в офіційних паперах, або одне з них є преферовано?

Answer (score 15):

#### «Словник української мови» в 11 томах (1971)

Каже, що *доня* — пестливе, а *донька* — розмовне.

> **[ДО́НЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/donja)**, і, *ж.*, *пестл.* Те саме, що **дочка́**.
>
> **[ДО́НЬКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/donjka)**, и, *ж.*, *розм.* Те саме, що **дочка́**.
>
> **[ДОЧКА́](http://sum.in.ua/s/dochka)**, и, *ж.* 1. Особа жіночої статі стосовно до своїх батьків. <…>

Відповідно в офіційних документах доречніше застосовувати *дочка*.

#### «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010)

Вже не подає біля слова *донька* поміту «розмовне»:

> **[ДО́НЬКА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23937&page=825)**, и, *ж.* Те саме, що **дочка́**.

При цьому дефініції інших двох слів не змінюються: *[до́ня](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23936&page=806)* так само пестливе, *[дочка́](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24712&page=825)* так само «особа жіночої статі стос. до своїх батьків»

#### Висновок

Якщо Вам все одно, то я би застосовував *дочка*. По-перше, (якщо припустити, що конотація слова *донька* справді змінилася, а не це помилка в одному зі словників) воно не розмовне навіть з точки зору найбільших ретроградів; по-друге, якщо *доня* — пестливе, то яке тоді *донька*? Проте якщо Ви маєте якісь уподобання саме до слова *до́нька*, то особисто я не бачу причин не застосовувати його.

Answer (score 0):

здається, що "дочка" - калька з російської. я не перевіряв у старих українських(справді українських, а не радянсько-українських!) словниках, але готовий битись об заклад, що слово "донька" нічим не гірше, зате рідніше і більш милозвучне! Можна спитати Пономаріва, що правильніще...

Comment: То краще перевірте (чи спитайте Пономаріва) і відредагуйте (edit) Вашу відповідь. Бо наразі Ваша відповідь, на жаль, не виглядає ґрунтовною. Отут: [R2U](http://r2u.org.ua/), [Hrinchenko](http://hrinchenko.com/) — є старі словники; отут: [mova.info corpus](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx), [Google Books (uk)](//www.google.com/webhp?tbm=bks&lr=lang_uk) — можна самому пошукати в книжках.

Comment: Будь ласка, не залишайте Вашу відповідь так, як є. Якщо знайдете підтвердження Вашій позиції — вставте; якщо ні: приберіть відповідь або відредагуйте, мовляв, помилився. Поки що єдине, що я бачу, що хоча б небезпосередньо підтримує «доньку» — це частота вжитків у [частотному словнику linguisto.eu](http://linguisto.eu/freq) — здається, начебто вживаність «донька» росте, а «дочка» — спадає чи не змінюється (але це лише вживаність протягом останніх років, а не кальковане походження; можливо, сучасне сприйняття милозвучності — й справді до «доньки»).

Comment: З блогу проф. Пономарева (https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40405563):
Що правильніше - дочка чи донька, запитує читач Андрій.
Обидва слова цілком українські (до речі, слово до’нька неправильно наголошують: кажуть донька’).

Слово донька має пестливий відтінок, а дочка, крім першого, нейтрального значення, має ще й таке: ласкаве звертання літньої людини до молодої жінки. Наприклад:

"Мавка: Ох, як довго я спала.

Лісовик: Довго, дочко". (Леся Українка).